# I would appreciate any help proving that $65$ is not a prime using Fermat's theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I need to figure out a way to show: $65$ is not a prime

so far, I figured I prove it by contradiction so I assume is is prime and therefore it satisfies Fermat with $n = 2$ and $p = 65$

$$\implies 2 ^ {65} \equiv 2 \pmod {65}$$

$$\implies 2 ^ {64} \equiv 1 \pmod {65}$$

After this I have no idea how to break down the 64 to show that there is a contradiction.

Thank you

Comment: What is $2^{12}\pmod{65}$?

Comment: I believe it is 1

Comment: Sorry, meant to square it, so $(2^6)^2=2^{12}=1\pmod {65}$, and $64=12\cdot 5+4$, so...

Comment: Thank you very much Abiessu !

Comment: I originally read this as "proving $65$ is not a cube using Fermat's theorem". But this can also be proved as follows: $65 = 4^3 + 1^3$, and if $65$ were a cube then this would contradict Fermat's Last Theorem :)

Comment: I like your style !

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that $65$ is a prime, we must have $2^{65}\equiv 2\pmod{65}$.

However,

$$ 2^{65} \equiv \frac{1}{2}(2^6)^{11} \equiv \frac{1}{2}(-1)^{11}\equiv -\frac{1}{2}\equiv -33\equiv 32\pmod{65}$$
hence $65$ is not a prime.